# Import xml into xfa form on the web server

Tags: php, xml, forms, pdf, xfa

I'm trying to import some XML data into XFA form through web server.

So, I have a HTML form which user populate, that data is stored in MySQL database. On other side I have an XFA form created in LiveCycle and wrapped in PDF, when user finish populating online form I need to place user's data in the XFA form and trigger the print it.

How can I do this? So far I had success using FPDM for real PDF form. Can I somehow convert XFA to real PDF form? Will I be able to print the PDF file through browser automatically when user clicks the button?

This is what I found, but it's too expensive to buy a licence:

http://itextpdf.com/product/xfa_worker

I'm struggling with this one for a while, any help is welcoming.

Thanks in advance,
VUkasin

Comment: You can use PDFtk (which is not free but much cheaper than iText) or earlier versions of iText (latest free of charge version would be 4.1.6).

Comment: I was researching about PDFTK and it doesn't have support for XFA forms. I will try with earlier version of iText.

Comment: @Wolf87: I want to read XFA data from form pdf in php. I am not getting any solution in php. Please help me.

Comment: @Wolf87: I have solution in java using iText. But i want to implement it in php. In php pdftk library is there. But this library is not able to extract xfa data from form pdf. So, please refer me any solution you have.

Comment: @Lakhan: This project is paused. I didn't work on it for a while. I know that I was using XFDF to populate XFA form.